# Why does geom_jitter replicates black points when we use aes colour?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I came across this issue while analyzing my data and I was able to replicate it with the example of the [official ggplot reference](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_jitter.html).

This code creates black points that seem to be the original points before jitter was applied with collors:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(cyl, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_jitter(aes(colour = class))
```

However, this code works fine, it doesn't show the black points:

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(cyl, hwy))
p + geom_point()
p + geom_jitter(aes(colour = class))
```

I was thinking it may be related to geom_point printing the black dots before geom_jitter, but if this is the case, why does it work fine in the second example, which follows the same order?

This is the image of the black points
[image]

Comment: You're not updating `p` in the second code snippet. Either chain with `+` or assign to `p <- p + ...`.

Comment: The second code snippet is actually the working one. :) 
And that's the point, even though I'm neither updating p or chaining, it works. It removes the black points and only the coloured ones remain. So why do I get the black dots in the first snippet, which is chaining?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`geom_jitter` is merely a convenience function, it is calling `geom_point` under the hood. Because of this, your use of `p + geom_point() + geom_jitter(aes(color=class))` is actually the same as

```r
ggplot(ggplot2::mpg, aes(cyl, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(aes(color = class), position = "jitter")
```

which is plotting the same points *twice*. You can clarify this a little by changing the color of the original points:

```r
ggplot(ggplot2::mpg, aes(cyl, hwy)) + 
  geom_point(color = "red") +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = class))
```

[image: ggplot of mpg with red points]

If you want jittered points, use *either* `geom_point(position = "jitter")` *or* `geom_jitter()`, not both.

Comment: Got it. Your example with the red color made it really clear. I thought I was supposed call both functions. Now I got why my second snippet "works". Because I'm not actually changing p in the second line, the third line doesn't acually "remove" the black dots, because I didn't even added them to p, I had just printed them, right? Then in the 3rd line I just print the coloured ones. Great, thank you!

Comment: Yes, `p` is fresh in both calls, two graphic calls.